# How to map an ephemeral port to a pid?

Tags: port, tcp, netstat, pid, lsof

I have a RHEL server with several apps on it and I am attempting to figure out which one of them is making calls to an external web service. I have TCP dumps that show the calls being made and through various tools I am able to determine what ephemeral port is making those calls. However, I am unable to figure out how to map that ephemeral port to a pid. I am aware that I can use `lsof -i` to map bound ports to pids, but this is not my problem.

Is there any way to map an in-use ephemeral port to a pid or some other indicator as to what file is making the call?

Comment: What makes you think lsof -i won't work for ephemeral ports? Are you just having trouble running lsof in the right time window?

Comment: I think that may be it. Whenever I run lsof against this particular connection, there is nothing in the PID/Program column. May be a timing issue.

Comment: You could try lsof's repeat mode. Add the option -r1 to have it poll every second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lsof -i $PROTOCOL:$PORT
fuser $PORT/$PROTOCOL
netstat -np | grep $PORT
```

Any of those should work. Below is sample output showing my mail client using ephemeral port 56375 to talk to an IMAP server for further explanation:

```
$ sudo netstat -np | grep 56375
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.1:56375      217.70.184.11:993       ESTABLISHED 3256/thunderbird

$ fuser 56375/tcp
56375/tcp:            3256

$ lsof -i tcp:56375
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
thunderbi 3256   me     87u  IPv4 510573      0t0  TCP hostname:56375->example.com:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
```

Answer (score 2):

`netstat` will list all pid and port respective to each other.
`netstat -nlp` will provide you port to pid mapping.